# Decimal point issue on cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

I there, I'm trying making my first cocoa app, but I'm having problems with float numbers because of the regional settings.

If I write on the TextBox the float number 1.2 I only can get the number 1, but If I write on the same TextBox the same float number but this time with the ',' sign instead (1,2) I can get the right float value.

How can I bypass the regional settings?

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to bypass the regional settings, you want to use a [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert the string in the TextBox to a number.

Comment: I know it seems like a pain but you won't believe how many problems you will bypass by learning how to use NSNumberFormatter.